# C++ Input Validation (Time)

Tags: c++, validation

Hello I am trying to make an input validation if statement for time. The user will enter a number and if it is an invalid number involving time (IE a negative number, or 25 hours) the code will display "Invalid Input" and return you to the previous question so you can reenter valid input. Here is what I have so far, but it does not seem to be working.

```
cout << "Please enter the current processing hour." << endl;
    cin >> hr;          
    if (hr >= 0 && hr < 24)
        cout << "Invalid Input, try again.";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the current processing minute." << endl;
    cin >> min;
    if (min >= 0 && min < 60)
        cout << "Invalid Input, try again.";
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Please enter the current processing second." << endl;
    cin >> sec;
    if (sec >= 0 && sec < 60)
        cout << "Invalid Input, try again.";
    cout << endl;
```

Comment: can you tell us what isnt working?

Comment: I'm trying to start my car but it does not seem to be working. Can you help me? (It really helps to describe *precisely* what you tried and *precisely* what went wrong.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a loop so it can go back and try again:

```
while(1) {
    cout << "Please enter the current processing hour." << endl;
    cin >> hr;          
    if (hr >= 0 && hr < 24)
        break;
    cout << "Invalid Input, try again.";
}
cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your conditions are bad:

I'll give you one of them:

if (hr >= 0 && hr < 24)

should be

if (hr < 0 || hr > 23)

This is assuming hours can be from 0 to 23. ( as Mike suggested below )

Answer (score 0):

Your code has no loop. Your statements just execute and then stop. You need some form of looping until the input is correct.

Also your `if` statement does not ha no curly brackets. So it will always just execute the very next statement if the condition is true and skip that statement if the condition is false. It is usually easier to maintain code if you put the brackets there regardless.

Here is an example snippet to illustrate what could work for you

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int hr;
int isValid = 0;

while(0 == isValid)
{
    cout << "Please enter the current processing hour." << endl;
    cin.clear();
    cin >> hr;
    cout << "Input '"<< hr << "'" << endl;

    if (hr >= 0 && hr < 24)
    {
        isValid = 1;
        cout << "Valid." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Invalid, try again." << endl;
    }
}
```

Note how i use a variable to track the inputstate rather than escaping the loop via `break;`. This allows a function to only have one way of exiting. Usually a good thing to reduce your error rate.

Here is the code a bit more elaborated:

```
#include <iostream>

int getAndValidateInteger(const char * question, int min, int max);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int hour, minutes, seconds;

    hour = getAndValidateInteger("Please enter the current processing hour.", 0, 23);
    minutes = getAndValidateInteger("Please enter the current processing minute.", 0, 59);
    seconds = getAndValidateInteger("Please enter the current processing second.", 0, 59);

    return 0;
}

int getAndValidateInteger(const char * question, int min, int max)
{
    using std::cout;
    using std::cin;
    using std::endl;

    int number;
    int isValid = 0;

    while(0 == isValid)
    {
        cout << question << " (Range [" << min << ";" << max << "])" << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin >> number;
        cout << "Input '"<< number << "' " ;

        if (number >= min && number <= max)
        {
            isValid = 1;
            cout << "is valid." << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "is invalid, try again." << endl;
        }
    }

    return number;
}
```